# ReplaceAll not working with change of sign

Tags: replacement

I obtain the following results

```
In: -q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0] /. (-q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0]) -> 0
Out: 0

In: -q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0] /. (q1[x, 0] - q2[x, 0]) -> 0
Out: -q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0]
```

Now, I'd want the second operation (related to the first one by a change of sign) to also give zero. Why this is not happening and how could I solve this?

Comment: You must taylor your replacement rules according to the full form of an expression. To show the full form: "FullForm[ expression ]"

Comment: `-q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0] // Simplify[#, (-q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0]) == 0] &` or `-q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0] // Simplify[#, (q1[x, 0] - q2[x, 0]) == 0] &`

Comment: @BobHanlon's solution did work, thanks. I understand that ReplaceAll won't work because the FullForms do not match each other, although this is still surprising to me.

Comment: Replacement are always literal, not logical. Instead of trying to match the expression, you can try the replacement rule `q1[x, 0] -> q2[x, 0]` which is logically equivalent and easier to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of using ReplaceAll as a way of asserting arithmetic relationships, but if that's what you really want, then try something like this:

```
-q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0] /. (q1[x, 0] -> q2[x, 0])
```

Comment: That does work, but I'd like it to work also with that particular expression, since it appears in a list of substitution rules I've created with MapThread and it may appear later in the computations I require in different forms. If you have any alternatives to ReplaceAll that can help in this case?

Comment: That's a big question. I don't have any idea what your context is. What I would suggest, and I know this is abstract, is to implement the _semantics_ of your domain/system in such a way that these arithmetic transformations show up explicitly and are handled automatically. ReplaceAll is a _structural_ thing and just is not a robust, maintainable way to implement other types of semantics.

Comment: Here's an example based on a simple modification to your original problem, i.e. just add another `q2[x, 0]`: `-q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0] + q2[x, 0] /. (-q1[x, 0] + q2[x, 0]) -> 0`. I assume that you'd want this to reduce to `q2[x, 0]`, but your left hand side now reduces to `-q1[x, 0] + 2 q2[x, 0]` before your rule applies, and so no transformation occurs. You'll be patching this forever.

Comment: So your point is that ReplaceAll will only substitute the 'exact' expression and so it's not very useful, right?

Comment: @Paquique Yes, ReplaceAll will not replace if an exact lexical match can be found. It's a very useful function, just not for what you want to do because yours is not a structural, lexical replacement.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but my answer is the same as @MarcoB’s